# Is the receptor of SARS-CoV-like viruses in bats still unknown?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, receptor, bats

A fairly detailed [2012 review (Whittaker et al.)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3397359/) on the Mechanisms of Coronavirus Cell Entry Mediated by the Viral Spike Protein noted that

> SARS-CoV-like viruses have been isolated in bats. In this case, entry does not occur via ACE2 and their receptor(s) is/are unknown; however, replacement of the amino acid sequence found between residues 323 and 505 with the corresponding sequence of the SARS-CoV RBD is sufficient to allow human ACE2 receptor usage [[46]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18077725/).

Is the actual (bat) receptor that allows SARS-CoV-like viruses to replicate in bats still unknown?